# Wrong types between reducer and state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an initial state

```
export const initialState: InitialStateType = {
  cities: [],
  loading: false,
};

export type InitialStateType = {
  cities: [];
  loading: boolean;
};
```

Then I'm creating my main reducer

```
const mainReducer = ({ loading, cities }: InitialStateType, action: Action) => ({
  cities: citiesReducer(cities, action),
  loading: loadingReducer(loading, action),
});
```

I'm getting an error for cities.

```
Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InitialStateType'.  TS2345
```

I think this error has to do with the fact that types of state are different in InitialState and redicer but I'm not sure how to fix it.

My reducers

```
export const loadingReducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: Action): InitialStateType => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: action.loading,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


export const citiesReducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: Action): InitialStateType => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.SET_CITIES_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        cities: action.cities,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Dispatching example

```
dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.SET_CITIES_DATA, cities: result });
```

All the help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that both `loadingReducer` and `citiesReducer` are defined to accept `InitialStateType` which is typed as following:

```
InitialStateType = {
  cities: [];
  loading: boolean;
};
```

But the actual value that is being passed to them is the state chunks (cities = array, loading = boolean).

You can fix it b changing the reducers to accept the state chunk and return it:

```
export const loadingReducer = (state: boolean, action: Action): boolean => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.LOADING:
      return action.loading;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


export const citiesReducer = (state: string[], action: Action): string[] => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.SET_CITIES_DATA:
      return state.concat(action.cities);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't maintaining the structure that you say in `InitialState` in your `citiesReducer` and `loadingReducer`.

The error that you receive is because you type state in `citiesReducer` and `loadingReducer` to be of `InitialState` type but it is an `array` in case of `citiesReducer` and `boolean` in case of `loading` reducer

To comply with the `InitialState` structure your reducers must look like below:

```
export const loadingReducer = (state: boolean, action: Action): boolean => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.LOADING:
      return action.loading,
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


export const citiesReducer = (state: any[], action: Action): any[] => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.SET_CITIES_DATA:
      return action.cities,
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Happy to have helped